# Selecting elements in a usercontrol using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web form that contains a usercontrol and I would like to be able to access the html elements within the usercontrol from the form page using javascript.

I tried the following:

```
document.getElementById('<%= usercontrol.clientid %>')
```

but this returned `null`.

I had a look around with firebug and found that the tags in the usercontrol render with clientids like usercontrolid_myelement. I'm guessing that something like this might work:

```
document.getElementById('<%= usercontrol.clientid %>'+'_myelement')
```

Is there a better/nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen through your question with my psychic powers!

Your problem is that your serverscript in your main page can't access the ASP.net elements of your usercontrol.

The solution is to expose the elements, or just the ClientIDs of the elements you need, through properties in the usercontrol.  Then you can use the ClientIDs in Javascript like you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to the javascript running before the html is fully loaded.

following results in null

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('main'));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">

  </div>
</body>
```

this is better and returns the object

```
<head>
  function foo(){alert(document.getElementById('main'));}
</head>
<body onload="foo();">
  <div id="main">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The html is fully loaded when the javascript runs. The problem is that there is no element on the page with the clientid of the usercontrol. All the elements in the usercontrol have clientids in the form: usercontrolid_elementid.

Comment: then you need to expose the child control that you want to select and use its ClientID. If you see it quickly getting messy to get this to work I'd suggest looking into JQuery so that you can get the desired element with a simple selector and not worry about ClientID

Answer (score 0):

If your using .net 4 then you can stop the generated ids from being in that weird format.
Just add this property the asp.net ClientIDMode="Static"
e.g.

That should make it easier to access in the dom from javascript.