# Can't access User-Control via javascript on the outer Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, devexpress

I developed my user-control with a `label` and a `textbox` (both of them are from `DevExpress`). 
I have a page with some controls including mine and javascript block. 
I realize that I must use
 `document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.ClientID %>")` to get access for user-control. But `document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.ClientID %>")` returns null.

Here's my code:
1) `Page.aspx` with user control

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var tb = document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.ClientID %>"); // returns null
</script>

<head></head>
<body>
    <rsoft:TextBoxControl ID="tbPosition" runat="server" 
      Title="Позиция" IsRequired="true" 
      ValidationMode="UnsignedInt" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</body>
```

2) User-control 'rsoft:TextBoxControl'

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="styleFieldLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Text="" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" />
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td class="styleFieldInput">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbValue" runat="server" Width="500px"
            ClientIDMode="Static" ClientInstanceName="tbValue">   
        <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="tbValue_TextChanged" />                     
            <ValidationSettings SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" RequiredField-ErrorText="Поле обязательно для заполнения" 
                ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ValidateOnLeave="false" />                
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>            
    </td>
</tr>
```

Does anybody know why `document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.TextBoxClientID %>")` turns into `document.getElementById("tbPosition_tbValue")`, but there's an html element "tbPosition_tbValue_I" not "tbPosition_tbValue"? It occurs when i'm using DevExpress controls inside my user-control. When my control doesn't contain devexpress but usual `<Asp:Textbox>` I don't have this problem.

Comment: have you checked the javascript rendered to the client to see what `tbPostition.ClientID` actually gives you? If it's your own user control, it may well be null.

Comment: I checked rendered javascript. document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.ClientID %>") TRANSFORMED TO document.getElementById("tbPosition"); As you can see, it's the same as usercontrol Server Id 'tbPosition', no prefix and postfix. What can it be?

Comment: ok, but if you check the HTML on the client side, is there actually an HTML element with an ID of `tbPosition`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328978/selecting-elements-in-a-usercontrol-using-javascript

Comment: @GrahamClark, I've created a public property TextBoxClientID in my control that returns tbValue.ClientID. Now js code loos like this:
`var text = document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.TextBoxClientID %>").value;`
If there was <asp:TextBox> inside my control, it would work perfectly! (I've checked it). Cause in js-console it looks like
`document.getElementById("tbPosition_tbValue")` and there's an element with ID "tbPosition_tbValue". But I use DevExpress textbox and the situation is: document.getElementById("tbPosition_tbValue"), but textbox rendered to input with ID="tbPosition_tbValue_I".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ASP.NET loads up the UserControl, it ONLY renders the contents of the UserControl.

So in your case it will just render the `<table>`, the rows, the cells, the contents of those. It will turn the `document.getElementById("<%=tbPosition.ClientID %>")` into `document.getElementById("tbPosition")` as it should do because this is what you have told it to do at runtime, but `tbPosition` is nothing when rendered out as html.

Your options are: Either write the javascript within the UserControl to access those controls, OR set your server controls to `ClientIDMode="Static"` This will ensure that you can put the correct id's of the controls into your javascript.

```
var tb = document.getElementById('tbValue');
```

Comment: Ok, I understood that there will be just tables, tr, td and <input>.

Comment: First option you suggested is not suitable for me, because I need to get access my controls on the outer page that contains it, outside user controls. The second option is useful sometimes, but if there's several user controls on the page they both will have ClientID 'tbValue'. So it's more preferable to use ClientIDMode="Inherit", in this case we have tbPosition_tbValue, tbCategory_tbValue etc. I've checked it out.

Comment: What i am saying though is you are never going to be able to access the controls via `tbPosition` because this is never rendered as html. You need to access the ID's of the controls which are actually rendered

Comment: Yes, Tim. I corrected my code, check out my new related question at the description please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `document.getElementById` after the whole initial DOM is known.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var tb = document.getElementById(...);
};
```

Comment: In fact, I put this getElemenyById in javascript client event handler. DOM is known already, for sure. Here I posted simplified version of code without any conceptual changes. Anyway, thanks.